# How can I use a Twilio Function to terminate a call to the PSTN after I pick up the call SID?

Tags: twilio, twilio-api, twilio-twiml

I'm routing outbound traffic from a phone server to a Twilio SIP Domain. I'd like to use a Twilion Function to call a webhook (or whatever the easiest way is to get the call SID to my web server) before sending the call along to an Elastic SIP Trunk.

It seems like all the call forwarding function does is let you use a static phone number, which wouldn't work.

The idea is to be able to query Twilio for details of active calls to build a more robust system on our end, and Twilio doesn't give you the status of calls "in flight" unless you pick up the call SID programmatically as the call begins. Thank you!